# Initialize var of one component when I call function of this component?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I run ngOnInit  of component A when i call function of this component A?

For example :

```
export class CompositionComponent implements OnInit { 
  measure = new MeasureComponent(this.http);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

myFunction(){
   measure.functionMeasure();
}
```

//

```
export class MeasureComponent implements OnInit {
configCompo;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfigCompo().subscribe(data => {
        this.configCompo = JSON.parse(data);
    });

functionMeasure(){
   console.log(this.configCompo)
}
```

but actualy, this.configCompo is not initialized when I call this function from Composition Component, because it is initialized in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even it sounds weird on your requirement as ngOnInit should be called automatically when a component get initialized. But if you still want, there're 3 other ways:

- call `measure.ngOnInit()` to init measure after it is created
- add `ngOnInit` call to myFunction in MeasureComponent `this.ngOnInit()`
- or add `ngOnInit` to MeasureComponent constructor `this.ngOnInit()`

And keep in mind that this.getConfigCompo().subscribe(...) is an asynchronous function, so you can't get the value right after it is called. You can get it in the callback function only

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have choisen the third solution.

Comment: Yes it solve my issue, but like you said this.getConfigCompo().subscribe(...)  is an asynchronous function, so i can't get the value just after it is called.
Function "functionMeasure" is called long time after it's initialization, so maybe it is why it resolve my issue, but i'm looking for to get the value in callback function like you said.
I'm beggining js so...it's even more complicated to understand all the features ahah